# How to match multiple words from a list in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Suppose I have a document with `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` in it.

I want to find (and preferably replace) all instances of some words in a list, e.g. `the`, `fox`, `dog`. The end result should match like so:

**The** quick brown **fox** jumps over **the** lazy **dog**

How can I do this with a single search, rather than searching each word separately?

Normally I would do something like `([Tt]he|fox|dog)` as a regular expression, but it seems Word doesn't support the `|` pipe operator.

I want solutions that are native to Microsoft Word, no add-ins or external programs please.

Comment: You need a macro do search for multiple words.   https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/7375-find-highlight-multiple-words-ms-word-document.html

Comment: @John if you add that as an answer (with some explanation/code copy-paste so it's not just a link), I can accept. I modified their code for my needs

Comment: I did that for you Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a macro do search for multiple words  -  such a capability is not part of Native Word.

The macro below can do this for you and search through your document.

Please see:

[Macro to find multiple words](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/7375-find-highlight-multiple-words-ms-word-document.html)

```
Sub HiLightList()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, Rng As Range, i As Long
StrFnd = "dog,cat,pig,horse,man"
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, ","))
  Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With Rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a VBA macro for that.

The following macro was found in the article
[Macro trick: How to highlight multiple search strings in a Word document](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/macro-trick-how-to-highlight-multiple-search-strings-in-a-word-document/).
It searches and highlights the strings "very", "just", "of course".
The article further explains each command in the macro.

```
Sub HighlightWords()
Dim Word As Range
Dim WordCollection(2) As String
Dim Words As Variant
'Define list.
'If you add or delete, change value above in Dim statement.
WordCollection(0) = "very"
WordCollection(1) = "just"
WordCollection(2) = "of course"
'Set highlight color.
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
'Set highlight to replace setting.
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
'Cycle through document and find words in collection.
'Highlight words when found.
For Each Word In ActiveDocument.Words
For Each Words In WordCollection
With Selection.Find
.Text = Words
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = True
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Learn about macros in the Word Help and also the article
[guide to installing macros](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm).
Note that to use macros, the document must be of type `.docm` and not
`.docx`.